# Reading inner json object with retrofit and rxjava

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to read response from server, but I have problem with inner Json

Json object that cause me so many problem: :(

```
[
    {
        "num_id": 1,
        "row": {
            "coord_shirota": "59.932723",
            "www": "www.anichkov.ru",
            "metro": "Гостиный Двор",
            "description": "Старейшее здание на Невском проспекте, императорская резиденция",
            "address_manual": "Санкт-Петербург, Невский просп., 39 лит. А",
            "obj_history": "",
            "oid": "3285",
            "work_time": "пн-сб 10:00-18:00",
            "ogrn": "2147483647123",
            "metro_distance": "584.0",
            "phone": "8(812)310-93-80, 8(812)310-43-95.",
            "inn": "7840325991",
            "street": "Невский проспект",
            "metro_dolgota": "30.333745",
            "home": "39",
            "name_en": "Anichkov Palace",
            "metro_line": "Невско-Василеостровская линия",
            "name": "Аничков Дворец",
            "town": "Санкт-Петербург",
            "for_disabled": "0",
            "addressline": "Санкт-Петербург, Невский проспект, 39",
            "district": "Центральный район",
            "country": "Россия",
            "obj_history_en": "",
            "subdistrict": "муниципальный округ № 78",
            "coord_dolgota": "30.341459",
            "description_en": "The oldest building on Nevsky prospekt, imperial palace",
            "metro_shirota": "59.933938",
            "type": "Исторический",
            "email": "anichkovmuz@mail.ru"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

My Api for request:

```
public interface SpbGovSiteApi {
    @Headers({ "Authorization: Token 60a368fde851f786532fdb4b65c6fdb189122666" })
    @GET("123/versions/latest/data?per_page=1000")
    Call<List<SpbGovSiteResponse>> getInfo();
}
```

My classes for response:

```
public class Row {
    private float coord_shirota;
    private float coord_dolgota;
    private String www;
    private String description;
    private String address_manual;
    private String name;
    //...getters
}

class SpbGovSiteResponse {
    private Row row;
    public Row getRow() {
        return row;
    }
}
```

My retrofit function:

```
public Observable<Map<String,String>> getInfo() {
    return spbGovSiteResponse(retrofit.create(SpbGovSiteApi.class).getInfo());
}

private Observable<Map<String,String>> spbGovSiteResponse(Call<List<SpbGovSiteResponse>> call){
    Log.e("gg",call.request().url().toString());
    return Observable.create(e -> {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SpbGovSiteResponse>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<SpbGovSiteResponse>> call1, Response<List<SpbGovSiteResponse>> response) {
                for(SpbGovSiteResponse item: response.body()) {
                    Map map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    //map.put("name",item.getRow().getName());
                    //map.put("longtide",item.getRow().getCoord_dolgota());
                    //map.put("latitude",item.getRow().getCoord_shirota());
                    e.onNext(map);
                }
                e.onComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<SpbGovSiteResponse>> call1, Throwable t) {
                e.onError(t);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

And at last my problem:

In observer I print it in log with throwable parameter from interface method `onFailed`.

```
04-05 18:52:01.019 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextDouble(JsonReader.java:909)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson$3.read(Gson.java:308)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson$3.read(Gson.java:302)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
04-05 18:52:01.020 14703-14703/ru.scapegoats.museumspb W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

And if I left class SpbGovSiteApi empty, my programm working wery well... so I decided that cause of this problem there -_-

If i comment it

```
class SpbGovSiteResponse {
    private int num_id;
    // private Row row;
    // public Row getRow() {
    //     return row;
    // }
}
```

My program is running without problems

Comment: Print out your `response.body()` and check if it is not null and has data that you intended to get. By the way, I suggest you to use GSON library to deserialize your JSON response into valid class Objects, this will make your life much easier.

Comment: If my field   `private Row row` will be  uncommented I can't entry in method onSucces ->I can't print body..

Comment: Could you provide logs of an error you get?

Comment: `04-05 17:57:55.130 11465-11465/ru.scapegoats.museumspb E/gg: error empty String` it's my actual error, not my text

Comment: This is only one line and it is not enough. We need to see stack trace of an error which is printed in `logcat` when error occurs.

Comment: I'am edited my post

Comment: Thanks for providing this information. As I see GSON fails to parse JSON because of formatting issues. Try to make every variable type `String` in `Row` class and check if error still occur.

Comment: Sooooo, I solve my problem, it was caused by convertion of types... it's can't cast field from JSON to float, when i change it to String, all problems disappeared)))

Comment: Thats what I suggested above. :) Happy to help.

Comment: You guessed first))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either make the type of the numbers `String`:

```
public class Row {
    private String coord_shirota; // <- String not float
    private String coord_dolgota; // <- String not float
    private String www;
    private String description;
    private String address_manual;
    private String name;
    //...getters
}
```

or make the response return them as numbers:

```
"row": {
            "coord_shirota": 59.932723,  <- NOT "59.932723"
```